# Spring Boot Data JPA query doesn't work with LocalDateTime.MAX

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT bs FROM BookedSlot bs WHERE bs.timeFrom >= :timeFrom AND bs.timeFrom < :timeTo")
Set<BookedSlot> test(@Param("timeFrom") LocalDateTime fromTime, @Param("timeTo") LocalDateTime timeTo);
```

And two tests

```
    @Sql(scripts = "/test-data.sql")
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        final Set<BookedSlot> res = unit.test(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.MAX);
        assertNotNull(res);
        assertEquals(1, res.size());//fails
    }

    @Sql(scripts = "/test-data.sql")
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        final Set<BookedSlot> res = unit.test(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.of(2050,1,1,1,1));
        assertNotNull(res);
        assertEquals(1, res.size());//ok
    }
```

And *test-data.sql*

```
INSERT INTO booked_slots (id, created_at, updated_at, time_from, time_to, user_id, service_box_id)
VALUES (1, NOW(), NOW(), '2040-01-01 08:30:00.0', '2040-01-01 10:00:00.0', 1, 1);
```

*test1* - **fails**

*test2* - **ok**

*BookedSlots.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booked_slots")
public class BookedSlot extends DbEntity implements Comparable<BookedSlot> {

    @Column(name = "time_from")
    private LocalDateTime timeFrom;
    @Column(name = "time_to")
    private LocalDateTime timeTo;
}
```

Database h2 (and the same is on MySQL 5.7, I just use H2 for integration tests)

*test.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum supported [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is `999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999`. Database doesn't support dates that far into the future.

[MySQL range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for `DATETIME` values is `1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999`

---

> **hibernate-core:** [LiteralType::objectToSQLString](https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/LiteralType.java) Convert the value into a string
>   representation, suitable for embedding in an SQL statement as a
>   literal.

Here you can see [LocalDateTimeType::objectToSQLString](https://github.com/maesenka/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-java8/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/LocalDateTimeType.java) method

```
public class LocalDateTimeType
        extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<LocalDateTime>
        implements VersionType<LocalDateTime>, LiteralType<LocalDateTime> {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.ENGLISH );

    //...

    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(LocalDateTime value, Dialect dialect) throws Exception {
        return "{ts '" + FORMATTER.format( value ) + "'}";
    }

    //..
}
```

for `LocalDateTime.MAX` it returns `{ts '+999999999-12-31 23:59:59.9'}`

Comment: Thank you, but... it doesn't explain why Java's 999999999 is not converted to MySQL's 9999 :)

Comment: It cannot be converted to prevent data lost (`999999999 != 9999`). I have provided additional explanation